# Authentication Password to install Adobe to stream movies 11.10 system

Tags: authentication

I just purchased a computer with Ubuntu from the University. They said it was freshly installed. I would like to stream media and watch DVD's for one thing. I tried to install Adobe, but I need a password to Authenticate. I rebooted the system and went to where I saw root@ubuntu:~#. It gave no options, just a flashing cursor. Any help? Sudo is already installed.

Comment: Ask whoever sold you the laptop for the password.

Comment: I can't until Wednesday, when the University surplus store is open. I'm impatient.

Comment: Reinstall?  I'll bet you your University will allow you to download the ISO on one of their local-network systems.  If you have another system around, burn the 11.10 (or 12.04) ISO to a USB device.  Then, boot on that laptop with the USB running the ISO, and clean-install.

Answer (score 2):

> and went to where I saw `root@ubuntu:~#`

If you got there, and know your username (which you select when you login), just type in `passwd username` and change your password to something new (it doesn't require knowledge of the old password).

Comment: when I login, I don't have to enter a password.